# IPFS read data from network

Tags: android, ipfs

I am working on one application, where I am using IPFS for storing and getting files.

I am using the following API for Android,

> https://github.com/ligi/ipfs-api-kotlin

As per the doc, I can get data from IPFS using following code,

```
ipfs.get.cat("hash code of IPFS file")
```

but here it returns everything in string format, even if the uploaded file is Image.

How Can I know the content type of the file and download the same format?

Answer (score 2):

IPFS doesn't allow to store metadata such as the content type alongside the content itself.

Something you could do in Java that worked for me:

```
private static String guessContentType(InputStream content) {

    try {
        String guessedContentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(content);

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(guessedContentType)) {
            return guessedContentType;
        } else {
            return MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to guess content type", e);
    }
}
```